# if statement in html angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table and I want to write basic `if` statement into `<td>`.

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage]">
  <td>{{item.id}}</td>
  <td>{{(item.name == "name 12" && 'xxx') || item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.description}}</td>
  <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
  <td>{{item.field4}}</td>
  <td>{{item.field5}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

What I try to do is: if `item.name == "name 12"` => set empty string otherwise leave it as is.

Something like that:

```
 <td>{{(item.name == "name 12" && '') || item.name}}</td>
```

However it works only if I put some String like `'xxx'` in my case but with `''` it doesn't work.

Here is a demo in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/912/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An empty string evaluates to false, so item.name will be used instead of the empty string. Instead of the empty string you can use single space, that should work:

```
<td>{{(item.name == "name 12" && ' ') || item.name}}</td>
```

Or if you really need an empty string, negate it:

```
<td>{{(item.name != "name 12" && item.name) || ''}}</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular [added the ternary (conditional) operator in 1.1.5](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/6798fec4390a72b7943a49505f8a245b6016c84b)  (test ? ifTrue : ifFalse) which you can use like this:

```
<td>{{((item.name == "name 12") ? "" : item.name)}}</td>
```

Which, if `(item.name == "name 12")` is true will return `""` and it's false will return `item.name`

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAWsA/914/)